# Windows CMD won't reflect path entry removal

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

The following is original path configuration on Windows:

> ```
> set Path=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.7.0_80\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
> ```

And I removed the path entry for JRE and my path looks like this:

> ```
> set Path=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
> ```

But still I get this:

> ```
> C:\tmp> java -version
> java version "1.7.0_79"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
> ```

Why won't Windows reflect path entry removal like this? And how can I remove path entry?

(My intention: My app expects Java to have been installed on users' machines; I want to test my app showing proper error message for non-Java installed machine; So I wanted to simulate non-Java installed environment by removing the system path entry for JRE; I know I can simulate that in another way but I'm just curious what causes this behavior in Windows.)

Comment: BTW, the tested version is Windows 8.1

Comment: Did you change the path in a cmd window? This will only have an effect on the current instance. Use setx for a permanent change. See `setx /?` or visit [ss64.com/nt/setx.html](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html) Another option is to use `where java.*`

Comment: open a new cmd session and try again

Comment: Depending on the history of the machine, there may be a copy of `java.exe` in one or more of the system folders.  You can type `where java` to see exactly where Windows is finding the executable.

Comment: @HarryJohnston "where java" is cool; I didn't know that :-)

Answer (score 1):

I used **where java** suggested by @HarryJohnston @LotPings and I got this;

> C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe

The problem was elsewhere; java.exe exists in 2 different path entries

So emulating non-Java installed system in Windows seemingly cannot be done by manipulating only path environment variable in a local (even global!) system...

Temporarily **renaming** the exe files above worked;

Of course, you should close or suspend any process or service using JVM before doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You should see: ["How do I set or change the PATH system variable?"](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) at Java.com site.

Windows 10 and Windows 8

1. In Search, search for and then select: System (Control Panel)
2. Click the **Advanced system settings** link.
3. Click **Environment Variables**. In the section **System Variables**, find the PATH environment variable and select it. Click **Edit**. If the PATH environment variable does not exist, click **New**.
4. In the **Edit System Variable** (or **New System Variable**) window, specify the value of the PATH environment variable. Click **OK**. Close all remaining windows by clicking **OK**.
5. Reopen Command prompt window.

Also you can do it with [`setx`](https://superuser.com/a/502368) command.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't mention clearly, but I wanted to do it for just a local CMD session without affecting global system path; my bad;

Comment: I wanted to upvote this answer, but I couldn't... my reputation was short; sad...